# Confirmation alert is not working on click a button , How to make this work with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button that delete all the records in a table in a database

```
<button name="delete-all" class="alert alert-danger delete-all" ><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Delete All</button>
```

I want when it's clicked a confirmation dialog  appears and if it's confirmed this happen :

```
$state = $connect->prepare("DELETE *  FROM data ");
$state->execute();
// Then a success message appears at the top of the page 
        echo '<div class="container alert alert-success" role="alert">Well done!  You  successfully  Deleted All Records</div>';
```

How to do that because when I insert a php script inside confirmation function An error occur :

unexpected <

```
<script>
  //confirmation function(){
         <?php
               echo '<div class="container alert alert-success" 
               role="alert">Well done!  You  successfully  Deleted All 
                Records</div>'; 
         ?>
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Also note `DELETE * ` is invalid.

Comment: Why is it invalid?

Comment: It deletes the whole row, you aren't telling it which columns you want to delete. Just `delete from table`.